# GLSL 1.2 + Textures Non Power Of Two

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glsl

I have read about using **sampler2DRect** and **texture2DRect** to use rectangular textures. My question is whether its use is recommended for creating sprites 2D using GLSL, or if there is another alternative to using images that are not necessarily a power of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need are [non-power-of-two textures](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/NPOT_Texture), that's something OpenGL has supported for *all* texture types since GL 2.0. So you don't need rectangle textures if NPOTs are all you want.

Comment: @JavierRamírez: If you're talking about a [rectangle texture](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Rectangle_Texture), why do you need them? How do they help in making sprites?

Comment: I have many sprites rectangular. Can the non-power-of-two textures help me with this?

Comment: @JavierRamírez: Help you *in what way*? You're not explaining the problem you're having very well. What are you trying to do that you are not able to do? Because the size of a texture really has nothing to do with the size of any sprites you put into it. Well, besides the obvious limits on how many sprites can fit, of course.

Comment: You're right. Sorry if I have not explained well. What I want to know is if I can use in my application glsl sprites, without any restriction as the size of the texture, or if the sprite is rectangular, etc.. My question is, if to use sampler2DRect and texture2DRect for it.

Comment: @JavierRamírez: Those are two completely different questions. As I said, the size of a texture has no bearing on how you use the *contents* of that texture beside storage limitations. If you want to put 50 24x48 sprites into a 1024x1024 texture, you are free to do that. That has *nothing to do* with rectangle textures, or even the NPOT nature of the individual sprites themselves. That's basic sprite atlas stuff. So again, what does the use of rectangle textures have to do with the size and shape of your sprites?

Comment: I think the problem is in how I make sprites. A sprite I do creating a polygon (square). Then I put a texture. My idea is to use rectangular textures. This in order to not be necessary to rescale the polygon using a square texture. So also my image will distort. Plus it would use more memory.

Comment: @JavierRamírez But to clear up your question from your first comment, a normal 2D texture (i.e. `GL_TEXTURE_2D/sampler2D`, not a rectangle texture) is perfectly valid to be of non-square size. There is absolutely no problem with a 37x80 texture. The only real use-case (if any) for rectangle textures is their different addressing behaviour (with texture coordinates being from `[0,width]x[0,height]` rather than `[0,1]x[0,1]`), which makes them especially easier to use if you want to use `gl_FragCoord` as texture coordinate for example.

Comment: Thank you very much @Christian Rau. You have solved my questions